# Why is Istanbul not reporting coverage for my branch?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, code-coverage, mocha.js, istanbul

I am working with [MochaJS](http://mochajs.org/) for unit testing and [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) for code coverage reporting. I am getting less than 100% coverage reports due to some areas seemingly not being executed even though through my tests I can confirm that they are.

[image]

Is this just a bug in [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) where it is having trouble tracking this branch? Is there a better way to arrange the code? I tried:

```
function mapRules(options, rule) {
  var custom;

  if (options && rule.id in options) {
    custom = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rule));
    custom.test = options[rule.id];
  } else {
    custom = rule;
  }

  if (typeOf(custom.test, 'string')) {
    custom.test = new RegExp(custom.test);
  }

  return custom;
}
```

... with the same outcome.

This isn't - obviously - something that is mission critical or causing any real problems but I thought I would ask in case there is a way to fix it.

Comment: can you try with `hasOwnProperty` instead of `in` ?  are the results the same? `if ((!!options) && options.hasOwnProperty('rule.id')`

Comment: I was using that style of checking because the value could be falsy; so `if (options && options[rule.id])` would not work as desired if `options[rule.id] === false`. @AvraamMavridis I did, just now, try `hasOwnProperty` with no change as well as `Object.keys(options).indexOf(rule.id) >= 0`. Thank you @DavidGreydanus I await their arrival; coverage of %86.11 is just unacceptable.

Comment: Can you show the test which you believe is covering that code/branch?

Comment: Unfortunately - or fortunately, depending on how you look at it - I am unable to recreate this issue. A bit of development has taken place since posting this code snippet and the changes have invalidated this question. Simply put, the tests are now covering properly. Sorry for the noise. Thank you for your help.